# Does SBT to support preemptive auth for downloading packages?

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory, ivy, coursier

I am running SBT 1.2.8 and my project needs to download packages from a repo on a privately hosted Artifactory instance. My repo is protected by basic auth. After reading a multitude of examples and instructions, I created a `credentials.properties` file in my repo.

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=artifactory.mycompany.com
username=my_username
password=my_password
```

I then added the following to my `build.sbt` file

```
credentials += Credentials(new File("credentials.properties"))
```

Then I added the repository to my list of resolvers in `resolvers.sbt`

```
"My Company Artifactory" at "https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/my_private_repo/",
```

I built my application and was able to download the protected packages just fine.

However, a system administrator at my company requested I turn on the “Hide Existence of Unauthorized Resources” setting in Artifactory. This setting forces Artifactory to return 404 errors when an unauthenticated user tries to access protected resources. Usually in this case, Artifactory returns 401s with a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Suddenly, my application was unable to resolve its dependencies. I turned the Artifactory setting off and then back on again and verified this setting was, in fact, the cause of my problems.

It appears as though SBT will not send credentials unless it is challenged with a 401 and a `WWW-Authenticate` header (with the proper realm). Looking at the docs and GitHub issues for SBT, Ivy, and Coursier, it seems this “preemptive authentication” is not a supported feature.

I spend many hours trying to resolve this in various ways, but I cannot find a solution. Here is what I have tried:

- Adding my Artifactory username and password to the repository url, so it looks like `https://my_username:my_password@artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/my_private_repo/`. This worked in my browser and a REST client, but not with SBT.
- Omitting the “realm” from my credentials file
- Switching to SBT 1.3.9 and trying everything above with the new version.

Does anyone know how I can get SBT to use preemptive HTTP basic auth?  It appears both Maven and Gradle support this (see links below), but I cannot find anything in the SBT docs.

Maven support for preemptive auth: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-does-my-maven-builds-are-failing-with-a-404-error-when-hide-existence-of-unauthorized-resources-is-enabled/

Gradle support for preemptive auth:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/386/files

I'm almost thinking of setting up a local proxy to send the proper headers Artifactory, and point SBT to use the local proxy as a resolver. However, that seems needlessly cumbersome for developers to use.

Comment: Did you manage to find a working solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

you are correct.

You can setup an AbstractRepository. See https://github.com/SupraFii/sbt-google-artifact-registry/blob/master/src/main/scala/ch/firsts/sbt/gar/ArtifactRegistryRepository.scala#L21 for example:

```
package ch.firsts.sbt.gar

import java.io.File
import java.util

import com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.wagon.ArtifactRegistryWagon
import org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.Artifact
import org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository
import org.apache.maven.wagon.repository.Repository

class ArtifactRegistryRepository(repositoryUrl: String) extends AbstractRepository {
  val repo = new Repository("google-artifact-registry", repositoryUrl)
  val wagon = new ArtifactRegistryWagon()

  override def getResource(source: String): ArtifactRegistryResource = {
    val plainSource = stripRepository(source)
    wagon.connect(repo)
    ArtifactRegistryResource(repositoryUrl, plainSource, wagon.resourceExists(plainSource))
  }

  override def get(source: String, destination: File): Unit = {
    val adjustedSource = if (destination.toString.endsWith("sha1"))
      source + ".sha1"
    else if (destination.toString.endsWith("md5"))
      source + ".md5"
    else
      source

    wagon.connect(repo)
    wagon.get(adjustedSource, destination)
  }

  override def list(parent: String): util.List[String] = sys.error("Listing repository contents is not supported")

  override def put(artifact: Artifact, source: File, destination: String, overwrite: Boolean): Unit = {
    val plainDestination = stripRepository(destination)
    wagon.connect(repo)
    wagon.put(source, plainDestination)
  }

  private def stripRepository(fullName: String): String = fullName.substring(repositoryUrl.length + 1)

}
```